# Smoothing spline with continuous 4th and 5th order derivatives in Python?

Tags: python, interpolation, differential-equations, spline, smoothing

I have some noisy time series that represent input parameters as a function of time for a set of ODEs. These noisy time series need to be interpolated and the derivatives of that interpolation function need to be continuous up to the same number of orders as my ODE solver. Otherwise an Nth order ODE solver will try to take extremely small adaptive time steps to deal with the discontinuous jumps in the Nth order derivative. So for example, for the standard RK45 solver in scipy.integrate.solve_ivp, all derivatives of the interpolation function up to at least 5th order must be continuous, I think.

What is the best way to create a smoothing spline in Python such that its first 5 derivatives will be continuous? I am having a strangely difficult time accomplishing this simple task. Below is a minimal working example showing that even when using a 5th order smoothing UnivariateSpline from scipy, the 4th order derivative shows discontinuities/oscillations and the 5th order derivative just explodes (~1e6 magnitude). This is despite me first gaussian-smoothing my noisy time series to help the interpolation function.

I suspect this is at least one reason why the scipy RK45 solver is taking such a long time to solve my system of ODEs -- its taking an unnecessarily large number of smaller timesteps (though I think the fact that I'm using the default solve_ivp tolerances could also be playing a role).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter1d
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

x = np.sort(np.random.uniform(0.1,10,500))
dist = lognorm(0.5,loc=1.0)
y_noisy = dist.pdf(x) + np.random.uniform(0.0,1,500)
y_smooth = gaussian_filter1d(y_noisy,10,mode='nearest')


spl = UnivariateSpline(x,y_smooth,k=5,s=2)
xx = np.linspace(0.1,10,100000)
yy = spl(xx) 
d1 = np.diff(yy) / np.diff(xx)
d2 = np.diff(d1) / np.diff(xx[1:])
d3 = np.diff(d2) / np.diff(xx[1:-1])
d4 = np.diff(d3) / np.diff(xx[1:-2])
d5 = np.diff(d4) / np.diff(xx[1:-3])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=6,ncols=1,figsize=(8,8))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.7)
axes[0].plot(x,y_noisy,'k-',lw=2,alpha=0.1)
axes[0].plot(x,y_smooth,'y-',lw=2)
axes[0].plot(xx, yy)
axes[0].set_title('5th-order smoothing UnivariateSpline')
axes[1].plot(xx[1:], d1)
axes[1].set_title('first derivative')
axes[2].plot(xx[1:-1], d2)
axes[2].set_title('second derivative')
axes[3].plot(xx[2:-1], d3)
axes[3].set_title('third derivative')
axes[4].plot(xx[3:-1], d4)
axes[4].set_title('fourth derivative')
axes[5].plot(xx[4:-1], d5)
axes[5].set_title('fifth derivative')
```

[image]

Comment: Nick ODell is onto something. In general, derivatives increase noise as well. This is likely a numerical analysis issue. I also notice you are using a forward difference scheme. You may want to consider a centered difference, particularly if you have noise, using [`numpy.gradient`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html). Also note that `numpy.diff` can do [higher order differences with the `kwarg` `n`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), although it is just recursive.

Comment: If you're not familiar with forward/backward/centered difference schemes, it's probably worth a Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a valid way to check whether a function is continuous at the fifth derivative. I think the timestep is so small that the plots of the fourth and fifth derivatives are getting overwhelmed by floating point errors. The fourth and fifth differences are so tiny that small errors have a big effect.

To test this, I replaced the spline that you fit with `np.sin()`, which I know has continuous derivatives.

[image: discrete differences of sin]

Sure enough, it says the fourth derivative is jumping around a whole lot. But that can't be - the fourth derivative of sine is just sine.

If I decrease the number of timesteps to 1000, it correctly finds the fourth and fifth derivative. Applying the same technique to the original function, I get this:

[image: discrete differences of spline]

Comment: Not thinking about it too hard so I may be wrong, but if you're using larger time steps you are also increasing the SNR, which is yielding better results at higher order derivatives.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense in retrospect. This also explains why RK45 (and higher order explicit scipy ODE solvers like DOP853) did succeed in solving my problem, even though it takes forever. This means it's probably something else in my ODE system that is causing the solvers to take very small timesteps (probably something to do with the different timescales that different state variables evolve on).